# How do I make a function that returns a list of tuples sorted by the last element in the tuple?

Tags: python, function, tuples, sorting

This is the code I am trying to run but it doesn't work. It says invalid syntax.

```
    def sort_last(tuples):
        return sorted(tuples, key = tuples[-1]


    x = [(7, 6), (5, 5), (2, 1)]
    print sort_last(x)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a lambda:

```
def sort_last(tuples):
    return sorted(tuples, key = lambda t: t[-1])
```

Comment: And fix this missing paren. Also, an alternative to the `lambda` would be to `import operater` and then use `itemgetter()`, e.g. `key=operator.itemgetter(-1)`.